# How to allow multiple successive undos in excel vba?

Tags: excel, undo, vba

I have an excel workbook that needs to allow the user to undo multiple changes within a worksheet.  I have searched online in every forum that I can think of and have not been able to find an answer for this.  I realize that there is an issue with the undo issue in excel when macro's are run, and have been able to handle this using code derived from [here](http://j-walk.com/ss/excel/tips/tip23.htm).

This is my current process:

1. Create global variables to hold the initial state of the workbook, and the changes.  Code is as follows:

   ```
   Private Type SaveRange
       Val As Variant
       Addr As String
   End Type

   Private OldWorkbook As Workbook
   Private OldSheet As Worksheet
   Private OldSelection() As SaveRange
   Private OldSelectionCount As Integer
   Private InitialState() As SaveRange
   Private InitialStateCount As Integer
   ```
2. Get the initial state of the workbook by building an array (InitialState) holding the values of all the cells in the Workbook_Open sub.  Code is as follows:

   ```
   Private Sub Workbook_Open()
       GetInitialCellState
   End Sub

   Private Sub GetInitialCellState()
       Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, count As Integer
       Dim cellVal As String
       Dim sampID As Range, cell As Range
       Dim e1664 As Workbook
       Dim rawData As Worksheet
       Dim table As Range
       Dim LastRow As Integer, LastCol As Integer

       LastRow = Worksheets("Raw_Data").Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
       LastCol = Worksheets("Raw_Data").UsedRange.Columns.count
       Set e1664 = ThisWorkbook
       Set rawData = e1664.Sheets("Raw_Data")
       Set sampID = rawData.Range("SAMPLEID").Offset(1)
       Set table = rawData.Range(sampID, "R" & LastRow)

       i = 0
       j = 0
       count = 0
       ReDim InitialState(i)
       For i = 0 To (LastRow - sampID.Row)
           For j = 0 To LastCol
               ReDim Preserve InitialState(count)
               InitialState(count).Addr = sampID.Offset(i, j).address
               InitialState(count).Val = sampID.Offset(i, j).Value
               count = count + 1
           Next j
       Next i
       InitialStateCount = count - 1
   End Sub
   ```
3. When a value is entered into a cell, store the value entered into another array (OldSelection) holding the value entered.  This is done in the Workbook_Change sub.  The important parts here are the **Call SaveState(OldSelectionCount, Target.Cells.address, Target.Cells.Value)** and **Application.OnUndo "Undo the last action", "GI.OR.E1664.20150915_DRAFT.xlt!Sheet1.RevertState"** pieces which are shown in numbers 4 and 5 below. Code is as follows:

   ```
   Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
       Dim cell As Range, InWtRange As Boolean
       Dim y As Integer, x As Integer, count As Integer
       Dim LastRow As Integer

       'This saves the changed values of the cells   
       Call SaveState(OldSelectionCount, Target.Cells.address, Target.Cells.Value)

   try:
       y = Me.Range("SampleID").Row

       If Target.Column > 5 And Target.Column < 8 Then
           If Range("A" & Target.Row).Value = Range("A" & Target.Row + 1).Value Then
               If Range("A" & Target.Row + 1).Value <> "" Then
                   Range(Target.address).Offset(1).Value = Range(Target.address).Value
               End If
           End If
       Else
           'If initial pan weight add start date
           If Target.Column = 8 Then
               If Target.Cells.Text <> "" Then
                   If Not IsNumeric(Target.Cells.Value) Then
                       GoTo Finally
                   Else
                       Application.EnableEvents = False
                       Range("StartDate").Offset(Target.Cells.Row - y).Value = Format(Now(), "MM/DD/YY HH:NN:SS")
                       Application.EnableEvents = True
                   End If
               Else
                   Application.EnableEvents = False
                   Range("StartDate").Offset(Target.Cells.Row - y).Value = ""
                   Application.EnableEvents = True
               End If
           End If
       End If

       LastRow = Worksheets("Raw_Data").Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
       For Each cell In Target.Cells
               'Debug.Print Target.Cells.Address
           If cell.Value <> "" Then
               If Not IsNumeric(cell.Value) Then GoTo Finally
               Select Case cell.Column
                   Case 9, 11, 13
                       Application.EnableEvents = False
                       If CalcHEM(cell.Row - y, cell.Column) Then
                       End If
                       Application.EnableEvents = True
                   Case Else
                       'Do nothing yet
                   End Select
               'Cells(Target.Row + 1, Target.Column).Select
           End If
       Next

       'This will allow the changed values to be undone
       Application.OnUndo "Undo the last action", "GI.OR.E1664.20150915_DRAFT.xlt!Sheet1.RevertState"

   Finally:
       If Application.EnableEvents = False Then Application.EnableEvents = True
       Exit Sub

   Catch:
       MsgBox "An error has occurred in the code execution." & vbNewLine _
              & "The message text of the error is: " & Error(Err), vbInformation, "TSSCalcs.AddQC"
       Resume Finally

   End Sub
   ```
4. The SaveState Sub will save add to the OldSelection array, any values that have changed.  Code is as follows:

   ```
   Private Sub SaveState(count As Integer, Addr As String, Val As Double)
       Dim i As Integer
       Dim cell As Range

       If TypeName(Selection) <> "Range" Or Selection.count > 1 Then Exit Sub

       ReDim Preserve OldSelection(count)
       Set OldWorkbook = ActiveWorkbook
       Set OldSheet = ActiveSheet
       For Each cell In Selection
           OldSelection(count).Addr = Addr
           OldSelection(count).Val = Val
       Next cell
       OldSelectionCount = OldSelectionCount + 1
   End Sub
   ```
5. The RevertState Sub will undo ONLY THE LAST ACTION!  I am unable to allow more than the last entry to be undone.  Code is as follows:

   ```
   Private Sub RevertState()
       Dim i As Integer, index As Integer
       Dim prevItem As SaveRange
       Dim address As String

       OldWorkbook.Activate
       OldSheet.Activate

       Application.EnableEvents = False
           address = OldSelection(OldSelectionCount - 1).Addr
           OldSelectionCount = OldSelectionCount - 2
           If OldSelectionCount <= 0 Then
               ReDim OldSelection(0)
               For i = 0 To InitialStateCount
                   If InitialState(i).Addr = address Then
                       prevItem.Val = InitialState(i).Val
                       index = i
                   End If
               Next i
               Range(InitialState(index).Addr).Formula = prevItem.Val
           Else
               ReDim Preserve OldSelection(OldSelectionCount)
               For i = 0 To OldSelectionCount
                   If OldSelection(i).Addr = address Then
                       prevItem.Val = OldSelection(i).Val
                       index = i
                   End If
               Next i
               'OldSelectionCount = OldSelectionCount + 1
               Range(OldSelection(index).Addr).Formula = prevItem.Val
           End If
           OldSelectionCount = OldSelectionCount + 1
       Application.EnableEvents = True
   End Sub
   ```

Does anyone know of a way to allow multiple undo's to be done?

Any help to solve this issue would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Had worked on a similar issue in the past (not in Excel), and the idea was to create a sort of stack structure to save a sequence of states, instead of saving only one state.

Comment: You may find this article and example interesting for your project. Creating An Undo Handler To Undo Changes Done By Excel VBA<http://www.jkp-ads.com/Articles/UndoWithVBA00.asp>  and undo handler example <http://www.jkp-ads.com/downloadscript.asp?filename=UndoHandler.zip>

Comment: The two links you sent me don't work, but the link that contains the information you are referring to should be [here](http://www.jkp-ads.com/Articles/UndoWithVBA00.asp).  Although this is good information, the code needs more debugging than it is worth.  The real issue is with the onUndo method.  I would like to use Microsoft's, if possible, but might be easier to just write my own.  If I find a solution I'll post it.

Comment: Did you get this resolved?

Comment: See the answer below as to how I resolved this issue.

Answer (score 1):

After researching the Undo function on MSDN [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838189.aspx), I found that the Application.Undo function only undoes the last action taken by the user.  Instead of trying to get Microsoft's undo functionality to work, I have added my own undo and redo buttons which function the same as Microsoft's buttons.  I have added two class modules: ActionState (holds the properties for workbook, worksheet, address and value of a cell)
ActionStates (a collection ActionState objects along with functions for adding, removing, getting an item, clearing the collection, counting, and properties for the CurrentState, and InitialState of the worksheet).
The new process is as follows:

1. Get the initial state of all the cells in the worksheet and add these to the undo stack array (see GetInitialCellStates() method within UndoFuntionality module).
2. When an item is added to a cell, add the address and value to the array (see SaveState() method within UndoFunctionality module) and update the index of the current state to the most recently added value.  Repeat this step with any additional values.
3. When this is done, it enables the undo button.
4. If the undo button is pressed, it will decrement the index of the current state and enable the redo button (see RevertState() function within UndoFunctionality module).
5. If the redo button is pressed it will increment the index of the current state (see ProgressState() function within UndoFunctionality module).

The code for the ActionState class is as follows:

```
Private asAddr As String
Private asVal As Variant
Private asWorkbook As Workbook
Private asWorksheet As Worksheet

Private Sub Class_Initalize()
    Set asWorkbook = New Workbook
    Set asWorksheet = New Worksheet
End Sub

'''''''''''''''''''
' Addr property
'''''''''''''''''''
Public Property Get Addr() As String
    Addr = asAddr
End Property

Public Property Let Addr(Value As String)
    asAddr = Value
End Property

'''''''''''''''''''
' Val property
'''''''''''''''''''
Public Property Get Val() As Variant
    Val = asVal
End Property

Public Property Let Val(Value As Variant)
    asVal = Value
End Property

'''''''''''''''''''
' Wkbook property
'''''''''''''''''''
Public Property Get Wkbook() As Workbook
    Set Wkbook = asWorkbook
End Property

Public Property Let Wkbook(Value As Workbook)
    Set asWorkbook = Value
End Property

'''''''''''''''''''
' WkSheet property
'''''''''''''''''''
Public Property Get Wksheet() As Worksheet
    Set Wksheet = asWorksheet
End Property

Public Property Let Wksheet(Value As Worksheet)
    Set asWorksheet = Value
End Property
```

The code for the ActionStates class is as follows:

```
Private asStates As Collection
Private currState As Integer
Private initState As Integer

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set asStates = New Collection
End Sub

Private Sub Class_Termitate()
    Set asStates = Nothing
End Sub

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' InitialState property
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Public Property Get InitialState() As Integer
    InitialState = initState
End Property

Public Property Let InitialState(Value As Integer)
    initState = Value
End Property

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' CurrentState property
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Public Property Get CurrentState() As Integer
    CurrentState = currState
End Property

Public Property Let CurrentState(Value As Integer)
    currState = Value
End Property

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Add method
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Public Function Add(Addr As String, Val As Variant) As clsActionState
    Dim asNew As New clsActionState
    With asNew
        .Addr = Addr
        .Val = Val
    End With
    asStates.Add asNew
End Function

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Count method
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Public Property Get count() As Long
    If TypeName(asStates) = "Nothing" Then
        Set asStates = New Collection
    End If
    count = asStates.count
End Property

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Item method
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Public Function Item(index As Integer) As clsActionState
    Set Item = asStates.Item(index)
End Function

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Remove method
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Public Function Remove(index As Integer)
    If TypeName(asStates) = "Nothing" Then
        Set asStates = New Collection
    End If
    asStates.Remove (index)
End Function

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Clear method
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Public Sub Clear()
    Dim x As Integer
    For x = 1 To asStates.count
        asStates.Remove (1)
    Next x
End Sub
```

These two classes are used in a new module called UndoFunctionality as follows:

```
Option Explicit

Public ActionState As New clsActionState
Public ActionStates As New clsActionStates
Public undoChange As Boolean

Public Sub SaveState(count As Integer, Addr As String, Val As Variant)
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim cell As Range

    If TypeName(Selection) <> "Range" Or Selection.count > 1 Then Exit Sub

    With ActionState
        .Wkbook = ActiveWorkbook
        .Wksheet = ActiveSheet
    End With

    If ActionStates.CurrentState < ActionStates.count Then
        For i = ActionStates.CurrentState + 1 To ActionStates.count
            ActionStates.Remove (ActionStates.count)
        Next i
    End If

    For Each cell In Selection
        ActionState.Addr = Addr
        ActionState.Val = Val
    Next cell

    ActionStates.Add ActionState.Addr, ActionState.Val
    ActionStates.CurrentState = ActionStates.count
End Sub

Public Sub RevertState()
    Dim i As Integer, index As Integer
    Dim prevItem As New clsActionState
    Dim Address As String

    'undoChange = True

    With ActionState
        .Wkbook.Activate
        .Wksheet.Activate
    End With

    Application.EnableEvents = False
        Address = ActionStates.Item(ActionStates.CurrentState).Addr
        ActionStates.CurrentState = ActionStates.CurrentState - 1
        For i = 1 To ActionStates.CurrentState
            If ActionStates.Item(i).Addr = Address Then
                prevItem.Val = ActionStates.Item(i).Val
                index = i
            End If
        Next i
        Range(ActionStates.Item(index).Addr).Formula = prevItem.Val
    Application.EnableEvents = True

    UndoButtonAvailability
    RedoButtonAvailability
End Sub

Public Sub ProgressState()
    Dim i As Integer, index As Integer
    Dim nextItem As New clsActionState
    Dim Address As String

    With ActionState
        .Wkbook.Activate
        .Wksheet.Activate
    End With

    Application.EnableEvents = False
        ActionStates.CurrentState = ActionStates.CurrentState + 1
        With nextItem
            .Addr = ActionStates.Item(ActionStates.CurrentState).Addr
            .Val = ActionStates.Item(ActionStates.CurrentState).Val
        End With
        Range(ActionStates.Item(ActionStates.CurrentState).Addr).Formula = nextItem.Val
    Application.EnableEvents = True

    UndoButtonAvailability
    RedoButtonAvailability
End Sub

Public Sub GetInitialCellStates()
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, count As Integer
    Dim cellVal As String
    Dim sampID As Range, cell As Range
    Dim e1664 As Workbook
    Dim rawData As Worksheet
    Dim table As Range
    Dim LastRow As Integer, LastCol As Integer

    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Raw_Data").Activate

    If ActionStates.count > 0 Then
        ActionStates.Clear
    End If

    LastRow = Worksheets("Raw_Data").Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
    LastCol = Worksheets("Raw_Data").UsedRange.Columns.count
    Set e1664 = ThisWorkbook
    Set rawData = e1664.Sheets("Raw_Data")
    Set sampID = rawData.Range("SAMPLEID").Offset(1)
    Set table = rawData.Range(sampID, "R" & LastRow)
    i = 0
    j = 0
    count = 0

    For i = 0 To (LastRow - sampID.Row)
        For j = 0 To LastCol
            ActionState.Addr = sampID.Offset(i, j).Address
            ActionState.Val = sampID.Offset(i, j).Value
            ActionStates.Add ActionState.Addr, ActionState.Val
            count = count + 1
        Next j
    Next i

    ActionStates.InitialState = count
    ActionStates.CurrentState = count
    undoChange = False
    UndoButtonAvailability
    RedoButtonAvailability
End Sub

Public Sub UndoButtonAvailability()
    Dim rawData As Worksheet

    Set rawData = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Raw_Data")

    If ActionStates.CurrentState <= ActionStates.InitialState Then
        rawData.Buttons("UndoButton").Enabled = False
        rawData.Buttons("UndoButton").Font.ColorIndex = 16
    Else
        rawData.Buttons("UndoButton").Enabled = True
        rawData.Buttons("UndoButton").Font.ColorIndex = 1
    End If
End Sub

Public Sub RedoButtonAvailability()
    Dim rawData As Worksheet

    Set rawData = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Raw_Data")

    If ActionStates.CurrentState < ActionStates.count Then
        rawData.Buttons("RedoButton").Enabled = True
        rawData.Buttons("RedoButton").Font.ColorIndex = 1
    Else
        rawData.Buttons("RedoButton").Enabled = False
        rawData.Buttons("RedoButton").Font.ColorIndex = 16
    End If
End Sub

Sub UndoButton_Click()
    Dim rawData As Worksheet

    Set rawData = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Raw_Data")

    If rawData.Buttons("UndoButton").Enabled Then
        RevertState
    End If
End Sub

Sub RedoButton_Click()
    Dim rawData As Worksheet

    Set rawData = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Raw_Data")

    If rawData.Buttons("RedoButton").Enabled Then
        ProgressState
    End If
End Sub
```

The GetInitialStates method is used in the workbook_open event as follows:

```
UndoFunctionality.GetInitialCellStates
```

And the Worksheet_Change event within the worksheet is as follows:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim cell As Range, InWtRange As Boolean
    Dim y As Integer, x As Integer, count As Integer
    Dim LastRow As Integer

    'This saves the changed values of the cells
    Call SaveState(ActionStates.CurrentState, Target.Cells.Address, Target.Cells.Value)

try:
    y = Me.Range("SampleID").Row

    If Target.Column > 5 And Target.Column < 8 Then
        If Range("A" & Target.Row).Value = Range("A" & Target.Row + 1).Value Then
            If Range("A" & Target.Row + 1).Value <> "" Then
                Range(Target.Address).Offset(1).Value = Range(Target.Address).Value
            End If
        End If
    Else
        'If initial pan weight add start date
        If Target.Column = 8 Then
            If Target.Cells.Text <> "" Then
                If Not IsNumeric(Target.Cells.Value) Then
                    GoTo Finally
                Else
                    Application.EnableEvents = False
                    Range("StartDate").Offset(Target.Cells.Row - y).Value = Format(Now(), "MM/DD/YY HH:NN:SS")
                    Application.EnableEvents = True
                End If
            Else
                Application.EnableEvents = False
                Range("StartDate").Offset(Target.Cells.Row - y).Value = ""
                Application.EnableEvents = True
            End If
        End If
    End If

    LastRow = Worksheets("Raw_Data").Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
    For Each cell In Target.Cells
        If cell.Value <> "" Then
            If Not IsNumeric(cell.Value) Then GoTo Finally
            Select Case cell.Column
                Case 9, 11, 13
                    Application.EnableEvents = False
                    If CalcHEM(cell.Row - y, cell.Column) Then
                    End If
                    Application.EnableEvents = True
                Case Else
                    'Do nothing yet
                End Select
        End If
    Next

    UndoFunctionality.UndoButtonAvailability
    UndoFunctionality.RedoButtonAvailability

Finally:
    If Application.EnableEvents = False Then Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub

Catch:
    MsgBox "An error has occurred in the code execution." & vbNewLine _
           & "The message text of the error is: " & Error(Err), vbInformation, "TSSCalcs.AddQC"
    Resume Finally

End Sub
```

The only thing left is to add two buttons to the worksheet and assign the macro used to the UndoButton_Click() and RedoButton_Click() events which will run the RevertState() and ProgressState() methods.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on the `Raw_Data` sheet, `SAMPLEID` and the table?

Comment: Also, the `CalcHEM` function is missing.

Answer (score 0):

I found a little trick using Application.OnTime. So it is possible to use Undo repeatedly. 
The Repeat button is not the Redo button. You can find it in the Edit menu or put it on your ribbon.
I am using Excel 2003.
Here is a working sample. Put the code inside ThisWorkbook module.

```
Dim Undos As New Collection

Sub Change()
  ' push previous cell values to the end of your undo array
  Undos.Add ActiveCell.Value
  ' change the cell values as you wish
  ActiveCell.Value = "(" + ActiveCell.Value + ")"

  PlanUndo
  PlanRepeat
End Sub

Sub Undo()
  ' make sure the undo array is not empty
  If (Undos.Count > 0) Then
    ' pop previous cell values from the end of your undo array
    Dim Value
    Value = Undos.Item(Undos.Count)
    Undos.Remove Undos.Count
    ' revert the cell values
    ActiveCell.Value = Value
  End If

  If (Undos.Count > 0) Then
    PlanUndo
  End If
  PlanRepeat
End Sub

Function PlanUndo()
  Application.OnTime Now, "ThisWorkbook.SetUndo"
End Function

Sub SetUndo()
  Application.OnUndo "Undo last change", "ThisWorkbook.Undo"
End Sub

Function PlanRepeat()
  Application.OnTime Now, "ThisWorkbook.SetRepeat"
End Function

Sub SetRepeat()
  Application.OnRepeat "Repeat last change", "ThisWorkbook.Change"
End Sub
```